# Autocorrelation returning non-significant values despite an apparent pattern

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I have just finished Chatfield and Xing's *The Analysis of Time Series, 7th edition* and I'm beginning to play around with some simple analysis. I have this graph representing the grand mean value selections from a bunch of participants over 30 game rounds.
[image]

By visual inspection, there looks to be a curious cyclic pattern of higher followed by lower selected values. This pattern makes some sense theoretically (given the field and particular data, though I will not get into it). However, when I run `acf(blastovertime$meanround)`, I get non-significant values:
[image]

I would expect a significant ac at lag 1... Is my experiment just simply underpowered?

TYIA

Comment: Could be, also likely that you are seeing patterns which do not exist and the ACF is alluding to that.

Comment: Fair enough. I presume the only way to know would be to considerably increase the number of rounds.

Comment: you could try to calculate acf only for the first half of the dataset. That is where one can see a pattern. The second half looks different to me, so I would agree with user2974951, this could be something only humans can see, but statistics can't :-)

Comment: yes, if you had more data, you would be more certain about effects